# Working With Nested XPath Predicates ... Refined

Tags: xpath

All great answers!  But the question deserves refinement ...

I've got the following sample XML ...

```
<objects>
    <object objectId="1123" ... />
    <properties refObjectId="1123" ... />
    <properties refObjectId="1123" refPropertyId="2311" ... />
    <properties refObjectId="1123" refPropertyId="4611" ... />
    <object objectId="2123" ... />
    <properties refObjectId="2123" refPropertyId="4311" ... />
    <properties refObjectId="2123" refPropertyId="8611" ... />
    ....
</objects>
```

... and the following XPath query ...

```
//object[//properties[@refObjectId=@objectId and not(@refPropertyId)]]
```

I thought this query would return all `object` nodes where there is a `properties` node that has a `refObjectId` attribute that equals the `objectId` attribute of the `object` node **and no 'refPropertyId' attribute ... namely object 1123 only, not object 2123** ... but it doesn't.  It seems the `@objectId` in the nested predicate does not refer to the `objectId` attribute of the `object` node.

Any ideas?  I know the XML structure isn't nested as you would expect, but there are reasons for this structure.

Comment: Do you have multiple object nodes within the objects node where the properties for a particular object occur just below tht object?

Answer (score 10):

Generally you should avoid using `//` where you can. I'd consider rephrasing:

```
//object[../properties/@refObjectId=@objectId]
```

In the expression provided, your nested predicate is actually checking for

```
//properties/@refObjectId=//properties/@objectId
```

of which there are none.

I hope this helps!

EDIT: Since the question has been updated here is an updated response:
 You added "It seems the @objectId in the nested predicate does not refer to the objectId attribute of the object node." You're absolutely right! So let's fix it!!

```
//object[../properties[not(@refPropertyId)]/@refObjectId=@objectId]
```

This should be closer to what you're after!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   //objects[object/@objectId = properties/@refObjectId]/object
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
//objects/object[@objectId = ../properties/@refObjectId]
```

I am not sure how your xml is. However, if it is in the following format:

```
<objects>
    <object objectId="1111" />
    <properties refObjectId="1111" />
    <object objectId="2111" />
    <properties refObjectId="3111" />
    <object objectId="4111" />
    <properties refObjectId="5111" />
    <object objectId="6111" />
    <properties refObjectId="4111" />
    <object objectId="7111" />
    <properties refObjectId="7111" />
</objects>
```

Then you should use the following xpath to get only objects 1111 and 7111. The result should not include 4111 because the properties where refObjectId = 4111 does not immediately follow the object whose objectId=4111.

```
//objects/properties[@refObjectId = preceding::object[1]/@objectId]/preceding::object[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all `<properties>` nodes that belong to a given `<object>` actually *follow* that object (your input seems to imply that), you could do:

```
/objects/properties[
  @refObjectId = preceding-sibling::object[1]/@objectId
  and 
  not(@refPropertyId)
]/preceding-sibling::object[1]
```

This should perform pretty well.

If you happen to be in XSLT, things get a lot simpler:

```
<xsl:key name="kPropertiesByObjectId" match="properties" use="@refObjectId" />
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="object">
  <!-- This tests for an empty node-set. Non-empty node sets can only happen
       for objects with at least one <properties> node without @refPropertyId -->
  <xsl:if test="key('kPropertiesByObjectId', @objectId)[not(@refPropertyId)]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

In the XSLT case, the order of object and proerties nodes becomes irrelevant.