# How to select all nodes such that their group size is higher than a given value, in XPath

Tags: xpath

I would like to select all `<mynode>` elements that have a value that appears a certain number of times (say, *x*) in all the elements.

Example:

```
<root>
  <mynode>
    <attr1>value_1</attr1>
    <attr2>value_2</attr2>
  </mynode>
  <mynode>
    <attr1>value_3</attr1>
    <attr2>value_3</attr2>
  </mynode>
  <mynode>
    <attr1>value_4</attr1>
    <attr2>value_5</attr2>
  </mynode>
  <mynode>
    <attr1>value_6</attr1>
    <attr2>value_5</attr2>
  </mynode>
</root>
```

In this case, I want all the `<mynode>` elements that whose `attr2` value occurs > 1 time (*x* = 1). So, the last two `<mynode>`s.

Which query I have to perform in order to achieve this target?

Comment: I don't get it. Why _the last two nodes_. So I guess you refer to `mynode` at position 3 and 4. However, for both of them the attr_2 value (value_5) just appears one time in other nodes. So the example you propose does not fit to your question (or maybe I am missing or misunderstanding something)

Comment: Yes, I meant nodes (mynode) 3 and 4. The value_5 of attr2 appears 2 times in *all* the nodes.

Comment: @Baduel, your question says "that appear a number of times (says x) in the **other** nodes", not "in **all** nodes". Hence the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using XPath 2.0 or greater, then the following will work:

```
for $value in distinct-values(/root/mynode/attr2)
return
    if (count(/root/mynode[attr2 = $value]) > 1) then
        /root/mynode[attr2 = $value]
    else ()
```

For a more detailed discussion see: [XPath/XSLT nested predicates: how to get the context of outer predicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595034/xpath-xslt-nested-predicates-how-to-get-the-context-of-outer-predicate)

Answer (score 0):

This is also possible in plain XPath 1.0 (also works in newer versions of XPath); and probably easier to read. Think of your problem as you're looking for all `<mynode/>`s which have an `<att2/>` node that also occurs before or after the `<mynode/>`:

```
//mynode[attr2 = preceding::attr2 or attr2 = following::attr2]
```

If `<att2/>` nodes can also accour inside other elements and you do not want to test for those:

```
//mynode[attr2 = preceding::mynode/attr2 or attr2 = following::mynode/attr2]
```