# How to find same elements with xpath

Tags: xpath

With the next xml, how coud i get the list of directors where two directors has the same LastName in one movie?

```html
<MoviesLib>
  <Movie Title="Batman" Year="2013">
    <Directors>
      <Director>
        <Name>Robert</Name>
        <LastName>Zemeckis</LastName>
      </Director>
    </Directors>
  </Movie>
  <Movie Title="Gru" Year="2012">
    <Directors>
      <Director>
        <Name>john</Name>
        <LastName>tailer</LastName>
      </Director>
      <Director>
        <Name>Emma</Name>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
      </Director>
      <Director>
        <Name>Lana</Name>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
      </Director>
    </Directors>
  </Movie>
</MoviesLib>
```

for example in this case would be: Emma Smith, Lana Smith

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XPath 2.0 expression should work:

```
for $d in //Director
    return $d[../Director[not(. is $d) and LastName = $d/LastName]]
```

I can't come up with a single XPath 1.0 expression since it doesn't support `for` expressions (see the question [How to get the context of outer predicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595034/xpath-xslt-nested-predicates-how-to-get-the-context-of-outer-predicate) for some background).

Comment: Man i love you, you saved me :)
really really thanks!

I will need your help in the future